# SolrJ addFilterQuery Being Ignored

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using SolrJ (v. 7.3.0) to implement a SolrQuery. For some reason, none of the `addFilterQuery`'s are being processed, while every other query builder helper function is working. I checked the final query with `toString` and the `fq`'s are nowhere to be found.

This is an example string argument:

```
{!tag=style}style:"winter casual" OR style:"formal"
```

I am calling `addFilterQuery` multiple times in my code.

Comment: So what does your _code_ look like? What does the server side log show?

Comment: It seems I have a scoping issue. ` var query: SolrQuery = new SolrQuery();` as a class field. Params in some class methods are being added, in one function, they are being ignored.

Comment: To clarify I am using Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that elsewhere in my code I was calling `query.set("fq", "type:value"`. `query.set` overrides any future query functions that use that same query field. Therefore, my calls to `query.addFilterQuery` were being ignored.